# Getting typescript compiler to ignore a line or accept an incorrectly declared function (tsx)

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, compiler-errors, tsx

I have a test I want to run, that checks to make sure the correct arguments are passed in. But my actual file already has the proper declaration, so it won't let me compile. I've tried to use the `// @ts-ignore` ignore comment but it doesn't work. How can I get it to ignore this error?

In my actual file, the declaration:

```
interface Props {
    maxValue: number;
    fill?: string;
    value: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
new CurvedMeter(props: Props) //how it is declared
```

In my test file:

```
it('throws if any neccesary props are missing', () => {
    const badProps = { maxValue: 100, value: 10, width: 100 };
    new CurvedMeter(badProps); // @ts-ignore <- does not work
    expect.any(Error);
});
```

Comment: why not declare the props as optional?

Comment: @toskv In my web app, they are necessary, and I feel that changing my declarations for the sake of testing defeats the purpose. This test is meant to check that I have `maxValue`, `value`, `width`, and `height` or else an error will be thrown, but the error is essentially premature and stops me from running my web app at all.

Comment: you could instead make a stub in your test that extends CurvedMeter and sends some default or null params.

Comment: @toskv I have included a test that ts won't compile for. Hopefully it will now make sense that I don't want to change my declarations at all.

Comment: so.. your problem is that badProps is not of type Props?

Comment: @toskv Yes, to ensure that I have my declaration correct in my file if I somehow mess it up. The question has been answered, but I appreciate your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hack" is to cast it as `any`

```
new CurvedMeter(badProps as any)
```

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly